# Is it possible to have the <error-page> servlet ignore some requests?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets

I have an application that uses the  feature to serve html pages with some error status codes, such as 404. However some of the requests are things like restful services or images which should return the JSON provided by the restful service, or nothing at all in the case of the image. I'm using Tomcat as the servlet container.

To clarify, there are several servlets which some serve images, and others html, plus a filter which serves html for various paths which can configured by the user. The 404 status generally comes from the lack of a filter or servlet mapped to the requested path. Hence the error-page feature is convenient to serve a response for paths that have no filter or servlet to respond to them.

So what I have in web.xml is (ignore spaces between / and *):

```
... several other mappings above

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/rest/ *</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ErrorPageServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/errorPage/ *</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

...

<filter-mapping>
  <!--This will serve content and not forward to the filter chain for certain paths-->
  <filter-name>MainFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/ *</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

...

<error-page>
  <!--Page not found-->
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/servlet/errorPage/404</location>
</error-page>
```

Is it possible to have the error page servlet ignore some requests but serve html in the response for others? Or should I use some different method for delivering error pages?

To clarify, what I want is that if someone GETs /foo (which doesn't exist) it goes to the ErrorPageServlet, but for GET /servlet/rest/foo/bar returns 404 response code it doesn't go to the ErrorPageServlet.

Answer (score 6):

I finally figured out what the issue is. The restful services were calling `HttpServletResponse.sendError()` instead of `HttpServletResponse.setStatus()`. It turns out there is a huge difference between the two, and only `sendError()` results in the  servlet being used.

The solution is simple, use `sendError()` if you want the error page to handle the output, use `setStatus()` if you want to write the output in the current servlet.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should set up your **web.xml** to redirect errors 404 to a specific page:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

at this point, you can implement your **error404.jsp** as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" isErrorPage="true" %><%  

    String url = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path") ;
    if ( url!=null && url.indexOf("restRequest")!=-1 ) return ; 

  %>
  <html><head><title>Error 404</title></head><body>Error 404<br>The requested URL <%=url%> was not found on this server.</body></html>
```

Comment: The problem with this is the data the restful service wrote to the response is lost, since /errro404.jsp get's a new response object which you are essentially returning with no output.

Comment: @SindriTraustason not sure of what you mean. On my side and having a website and restfull services on the same webapp, this kind of jsp error page like kkk sample were the only solution to keep this feature in the web.xml for the overall website (avoiding tomcat default message and tomcat version).

In addition I map the restservice exception, cf. http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/error-handling-in-rest-api-with-jersey/

Answer (score -1):

You can  achieve it with simple web.xml mapping. Example is

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExceptionServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>examples.Exception</servlet-class>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ExceptionServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/errorCodeRequest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JsonServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>examples.JSON</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JsonServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restRequest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps, the requirement is to serve a html body for 404 responses to all requests except /restRequest/**